# Ошибка в запросе связанных таблиц

Tags: php, sql-server, kohana

Есть Запрос:

```
SELECT gl.*
        , g.*
        , s.id dr_id
        , s.name
        , dg.*
    FROM gemolist gl
        LEFT JOIN gemolist_marks g
            ON gl.id = g.gemo_id
        LEFT JOIN drug_gemo dg
            ON dg.g_id=gl.id
        LEFT JOIN spr_drugs s
            ON s.id=dg.drug_id
        WHERE gl.id=1
        ORDER BY g.time
```

Синтаксис правилен, проверял 2 дня, В Среде MSSQL работает запрос без проблем. 
Но вот в кохане выдает ошибку:

```
Database_Exception [ 42000 ]: [42000] SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'. ( Incorrect syntax near the keyword '%.*ls'. ) ~ MODPATH\mssql\classes\kohana\database\mssql.php [ 83 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

возможно не хватает прав доступа к таблицам